# How to understand a battery specification

Tags: batteries

I read a data sheet of a li-ion battery to use it in my project. In the data sheet, it is mentioned that c5mah= 2200mah. I couldn't understand what that means. Please help me with understanding that.

Comment: Please, provide a link to the datasheet or, better, provide a screenshot of the relevant part. Unless it is a poorly formatted datasheet, I the exact form is "mah", without proper capitalization, i.e. mAh. If it is sloppiness on your part, that may hinder a proper answer. Especially how the "c5mah" is actually written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the data sheet, it is mentioned that c5mah= 2200mah. I couldn't understand what that means. Please help me with understanding that.

"c5mah" (sometimes written as C5mAh or C<sub>5</sub>mAh) means the capacity (in mAh) which a battery has, when discharged at the 5h rate i.e. the rate which fully discharges the battery in 5 hours, from a specified fully charged state, down to a specified fully discharged state (e.g. perhaps down to 2.75V for a Li-Ion cell, but check your specific datasheet).

In your specific case, the discharge current for the C5 rate is calculated as:

$$\textrm{2200mAh / 5h = 440mA}$$

So discharging a fully charged 2200mAh battery of that type, using a constant current of 440mA, would discharge the battery (down to their specified end condition - see the datasheet for details) in 5 hours. That's it.

You can think of C5 as being a tighter definition (more constrained specification) of "C", the battery capacity, as it gives a specific test condition i.e. the discharge current. Note that a battery's C2 (or C1) capacity value will be *less than* its C5 capacity value. Whereas its C10 or C20 capacity value will be *more than* its C5 capacity value.

Other test conditions will also be specified, as they affect battery capacity too e.g. temperature, end voltage (i.e. fully discharged voltage) etc. That is why there isn't a fixed value for "C" which applies under all test conditions.

(As others have said, in future, please supply a link to, or relevant screen captures from, any datasheet that you ask questions about.)

Comment: Good, detailed explanation. I didn't know about "C5"... +1

Answer (score 3):

**mAh** stands for **miliampere hours**, which is the total product of delivered current and time, which for this battery equals 2200. So in this case, if your circuit draws 2.2A (2200mA), the battery will last for one hour. If it only draws 1mA, the battery will last for 2200 hours. However, that's a rough simplification and ignores the impact of the **discharge rate** of your battery.

The discharge rate specifies the actual battery charge depending on the discharge current.

The higher your discharge current, the smaller is the actually capacity of your battery.

[image]
<sub>(source: [insideevs.com](https://insideevs.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/6a00d8341c4fbe53ef01b8d0808cd1970c-800wi.png))</sub>

So usually the capacity on the battery is specified for 1C current, increasing with lower discharge currents and decreasing with higher discharge currents.

Comment: It would be good if you added what 1C means. I appreciate many people will know (and work out from your text), but for someone coming completely new into this it's a term you've introduced and not explained. Also details of what mAh/g means. Specifically, the /g part as you did talk about what mAh is. Alos, what do you mean by "variety of the actual battery charge"? What sort of variety are there?

Comment: I know that what mAh stands for. But i need to know what is C5mAh and what does it stand for. I know  that mAh stands for capacity of battery and  C stands for discharge rate. But I cannot understand the meaning of c5mAh. in data sheet they mentioned the capacity with respect to discharge rate as other specification. Pls help with this

Comment: @shafeeq, you should amend your question to make that clear.

Comment: Can you add a link to your datasheet?

Comment: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/1781Battery_2200mAh.pdf